# Hyperparameter Tuning with Simulated Data

Tags: classification, svm, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm trying to create a SVM classifier which can predict some fault, and to train it I'm using **simulated examples** of the fault. Of course, the simulations are not perfect, but they appear to be good enough since I get reasonable results when predicting on the real examples.

What is the best way to tune the hyperparameters in order to maximise the performance on the real data? Using `GridSearchCV` does a good job of maximising the accuracy on a subset of the simulated data, but that doesn't always mean good results on the real data.

Any general tips on working with simulated training data are also welcome.